# Running a JS function based on each item in a SQL Item

Tags: javascript, php, sql, function

I would like to be able to run a function for each userID I have in my db. Since my project is a long term type thing, it will be called every 24 hours, fetch the userID's, then call another function (that accesses the spotifyAPI) with each userID to again update the database. I am still quite new to JS/SQL/PHP so any tips would be helpful. Here is what I got so far, all the other functions that will be used already work.

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', () => {
  $userIDs = conn.execute('SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM history');

  foreach($userIDs as $key => $user) {
    updateHistoryHlpr($user);
  }
})
```

This is what I came up with, but i get the error

```
  foreach($userIDs as $key => $user) {
          ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

which seems strange.
Any help greatly apprieacted!!

Comment: It looks like you are mixing PHP and JavaScript together. What is the file name that code is in?

Comment: server.js it is a node.js app

Comment: I am not familiar with node.js but `$userIDs = conn.execute('...` looks very PHP like. Presumably it it is node.js like too. Sorry not to be more clued up about node.js!